# How to cast from various unknown numeric types to double

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

My code will be getting a large amount of data from various sources in various numeric types that all arrive as type `object`, and for ease of use, I'd like to convert it all to `double` (which is way more than sufficient to represent the full range of the incoming data, and extreme precision is not necessary). I am certainly able to solve this problem, but my solution seems clunky:

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();

list.Add((int)42);
list.Add((short)42);
list.Add((float)42.1);
list.Add((double)42.1);
list.Add((decimal)42.1);

foreach (object valObj in list)
{
    Type objType = valObj.GetType();
    double value;

    if      (objType == typeof(int))     { value = (double)(int)valObj;     }
    else if (objType == typeof(short))   { value = (double)(short)valObj;   }
    else if (objType == typeof(float))   { value = (double)(float)valObj;   }
    else if (objType == typeof(double))  { value = (double)valObj;          }
    else if (objType == typeof(decimal)) { value = (double)(decimal)valObj; }
    else throw new Exception("Unexpected type");

    Console.WriteLine("Value: " + value);
}
```

I'd like to do something simpler, but this doesn't work:

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();

list.Add((int)42);
list.Add((short)42);
list.Add((float)42.1);
list.Add((double)42.1);
list.Add((decimal)42.1);

foreach (object valObj in list)
{
    double value = (double)valObj; // <--- exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'
    Console.WriteLine("Value: " + value);
}
```

Knowing that all of the data in the `list` is of numeric types that can legitimately be cast as `double`, how can I cast them as `double` without first casting `valObj` as whatever type it is?

Comment: What about `(double)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(double))`?

Comment: Or `var value = Convert.ToDouble(x);` which takes an `object` and returns a `double`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Convert.ToDouble()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3x7f55(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
foreach (object valObj in list)
{
    double value = Convert.ToDouble(valObj);
    Console.WriteLine("Value: " + value);
}
```

`Convert.ToDouble()` has many overloads which can take any of the following data types,

- `bool`
- `byte`
- `char`
- `DateTime`
- `decimal`
- `double`
- `float`
- `int`
- `long`
- `object`
- `sbyte`
- `short`
- `string`
- `uint`
- `ulong`
- `ushort`